# Apache serves empty file when symlinking to a php script outside of httpdocs

Tags: php, apache

As stated above, when symlinking to a php file outside of the httpdocs directory Apache/php serves an empty file. However if I change the extension to html the file is served properly as an html document. This leads me to believe that it is not a permissions error but could be something related to the php configuration (could open_basedir be causing this?) or Apache.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior?

EDIT: For anyone wondering about this, the problem was cause by the php open_basedir restriction.

Comment: Does the webserver have execute permissions on the php file?

Comment: Yes, and the server is actually serving the page rather then throwing a 403

Comment: @jessica PHP files don't need to be executable since PHP is running them, not the OS

Comment: Related to possible symlink cwd bug ? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50159

Comment: Voting to move to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on error reporting in PHP and check your PHP error log. 100% guaranteed that you had a fatal scripting or configuration error.

Comment: The thing is the exact same script works from the /httpdocs folder. Error reporting is turned on and I don't see anything in the logs

Comment: Using E_ALL level? Also, I've seen boxes where PHP couldn't write to its log file. Another possibility is that the configuration loaded is not the configuration you were expecting.

Comment: Yes, what configuration option could cause this? Is there something in the php/apache configuration that can disallow execution of php scripts outside of the httpdocs directory?

Comment: Try posting the relevant parts of your apache config and the output of `php -i`.

Comment: So it turns out this is being caused by an open_basedir restriction. I didn't see the errors because they were showing up in a place I'm not used to (we just switched our servers over to plesk and it handles vhosts differently then I am used to)

Answer (score 0):

I tested symlinking a PHP script from the webroot / htdocs. Worked just fine.

Made the following files

```
/some/directory/myphpscript.php      (the script)
/some/directory/htdocs/symlink.php   (webroot)
```

In the myphpscript.php I added a hello world script (`<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>`). The symlink was created from command line using the follow command when standing in /some/directory/htdocs/:

```
ln -s ../myphpscript.php symlink.php
```

Make sure

- User running Apache can access the file
- The symlink is correct. If your use relative paths, it must be relative to the webroot (e.g. `../../path/to/script.php`). Test the link by opening the file (e.g. `nano symlink.php`).

Check out the Apache error.log for error messages.

Comment: The links are properly created. The file is loaded and is not throwing a 404, and the same link works for an html file in the same location.

Comment: What is the name of the symlink? something.php? something.html?